# Failable convenience initializer with optional parameters

Tags: swift

I'm looking for the best way to structure a class with a failable convenience initializer with optional parameters. Current code:

```
class Member: NSObject {

    var uid: String
    let avatarURL: NSURL
    let created: NSDate
    let email: String
    let name: String
    let provider: String

    var posts = [Post]()
    var comments = [Comment]()

    // Initialize a member with raw data
    init(uid: String, avatarURL: NSURL, created: NSDate, email: String, name: String, provider: String){
        self.uid = uid
        self.avatarURL = avatarURL
        self.created = created
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.provider = provider
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init?(snapshot: FDataSnapshot){
        if let uid = snapshot.key {
            if let avatarURLString = snapshot.value["avatarURL"] as? String {
                if let avatarURL = NSURL(string: avatarURLString) {
                    if let memberCreated = snapshot.value["created"] as? NSDate {
                        if let memberEmail = snapshot.value["email"] as? String {
                            if let memberName = snapshot.value["name"] as? String {
                                if let memberProvider = snapshot.value["provider"] as? String {                                  
                                    self.init(uid: uid, avatarURL: avatarURL, created:memberCreated, email: memberEmail, name: memberName, provider: memberProvider)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I need to either initialize a member manually (init) or by passing a Firebase object (convenience init). If any of the optionals fail within the convenience init, I'd like it to fail.

Currently, it won't build because:

> All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before returning nil from an initializer

Not sure what I'm missing.

Any opinions about a better way to approach this are welcome.

Comment: `guard` statement was really good improvement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in failable initializers that the Swift team is still working on improving. As you say, all the properties must be set to something before returning `nil`, so set them to something (`""` or `NSDate()` in your case). It's a bit tedious, but currently necessary.

Just be clearer, since it can be a little tricky sometimes, here is one way:

```
convenience init?(snapshot: FDataSnapshot){
    if let uid = snapshot.key {
        if let avatarURLString = snapshot.value["avatarURL"] as? String {
            if let avatarURL = NSURL(string: avatarURLString) {
                if let memberCreated = snapshot.value["created"] as? NSDate {
                    if let memberEmail = snapshot.value["email"] as? String {
                        if let memberName = snapshot.value["name"] as? String {
                            if let memberProvider = snapshot.value["provider"] as? String {
                                self.init(uid: uid, avatarURL: avatarURL, created:memberCreated, email: memberEmail, name: memberName, provider: memberProvider)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    self.init(uid: "", avatarURL: NSURL(), created: NSDate(), email: "", name: "", provider: "")
    return nil
}
```

(In Swift 1.2, you will be able to stack all those let's together, which will make the code a bit clearer and let you use an `else` rather than a `return` in the middle.)

The key is that in a convenience initializer, you must eventually call `self.init`, even if you're going to call `return nil` later. (The Swift team knows this is annoying, but there are some corner cases that are difficult to deal with.)